# Android Studio Debugger connects and disconnects straight after

Tags: debugging, android-studio

I just started android programming in android studio. I want to test the debug function to see how it works, so I added a breakpoint. When I run the debugger it either says "Connecting to the target VM, address: 'localhost:860x*', transport: 'socket' (* last number of the port varies) OR it connects successfully and disconnects right after it has connected.

I don't have any idea on how to fix this.

Thanks in forehand.

Answer (score 2):

When the message `"Connecting to the target VM, address: 'localhost:860x*', transport: 'socket' (* last number of the port varies)`
appears, just unplug and plug your device, for some reason the device blocked the socket port.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is an old question and I haven't been doing Android programming for ages. The problem occurred on a different machine than my usual one and I haven't bothered about it afterwards. Thanks though, hope you manage to figure it out.

Comment: I figured out what was happening, that was a bad connection with my device with the USB cable